# How would EF find Down() migration on deployment of previous version?

Tags: entity-framework, rollback, entity-framework-migrations, webdeploy

We have a site that uses code first migrations and at the moment the deployment is partly manual, in that Up scripts are applied by hand after the new site folder is in place on the server.

I want to move to using web deploy properly and getting the Application_Start to apply the migrations automatically, I am concerned about what to do when rolling back to a per-migration site version. My mental logic tells me that the old version will not have the appropriate Down migration available to undo the more recent Up migration.

Am I correct or am I missing something?

Martyn

Comment: I have the same question. I assume you're right that the Down migration isn't available after the code is rolled back. (How) were you able to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

How are you generating the contents of the Up/Down methods in the Migration code? If you're using Add-Migration, then the Down() method should contain everything you need to roll back from a corresponding Up() call.

If you've manually changed the contents of the Up() method (or if some automatic process has changed it), you'll have to ensure that the Down() method is also updated to reflect the contents of the Up() method, to ensure proper downgrades, even if you have to modify the Down() method yourself.

Hope that helps?

If you can clarify further, I will try to answer in more detail.